# Has anyone got experience with Riak with a large dataset?

Tags: dataset, riak

I am planning on using Riak for a project I am working on and want to hear from anyone who is using for development / production systems. In particular I am interested in:

1) insert speed

2) maximum cluster sizes

3) select / search performance

Thanks

Zubair

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that customers include Collecta and Electronic Arts.

See http://www.masshightech.com/stories/2010/02/01/daily27-MHT-Exclusive-Basho-maps-unstructured-road-to-web-scalability.html and their case studies.

Comment: Wow, I was about to give up on Riak after seeing little real world usage. Maybe I should think again.

Comment: It seems that they are pushing quite strong. Eric Brewer joined their board, it's the guy that made the CAP Theorem.